# jqGrid: how to show and edit text containing \<a

Tags: jqgrid

If column text contains characters like `\<a`  only first character, `\` is displayed in grid. Remaining characters are not visible. 
In edit mode this data is displayed wrongly as 
`\<a< td=""></a<>`
If `\<a` is entered to cell using inline editing and saved, only `\` is visible in screen.

jqGrid setting `autoencode: true` is used. 
Data is read from ASP .NET 2 MVC controller from server in json format like

```
{"total":337,"page":3,"records":10094,"rows":[
{"id":"i88","cell":["\\\u003ca"] }
]
}
```

How to show and edit text like `\<a` in jqGrid 4.1.1 ?
If I remember properly, it worked in earlier jqGrid versions. Maybe jqID function changes proposed by Oleg caused this regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, that you just forgot to use the jqGrid option [autoencode: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) . If I use it I could reproduce the problem which you describe: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing-Andrus.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingFocus1.htm).

**UPDATED**: Your current test case can be reduced to [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing-Andrus1.htm) which has `formatter:null` in the `colModel`. If you remove the property the `autoencode: true` will work for the column.

Comment: Thank you very much. I verified multiple times that `autoencode: true` is present. If autoencode: true is removed ASP.NET exception: a potentially dangerous request has dedected ... occurs on save. If I autoencode: true if present this exception does not occur but I get this partial display. I can create testcase to you if you are interested.

Comment: @Andrus: OK! The demo which could be used to reproduce the problem would be very good.

Comment: Thank you. I sent testcases to you be e-mail.

Comment: @Andrus: Your column model (`colModel`) contain the following properties `"align":null, "classes":null, "formatter":null, "edittype":null, "editoptions":{"value":null,"maxlength":240}, "formatoptions":null` which looks like a garbage. I don't think that jqGrid can correct interpret the values.

Comment: @Andrus: The most critical is `"formatter":null` setting which looks like the dummy custom formatter. For column having custom formatter the option `autoencode: true` will not used and you have the described problem.

Comment: thank you. Using your invaluable hints I was able to solve the issue by creating special colmodel creator which does not emit null properties

Comment: If `\<a` is entered to grid column in inline edit and saved, this is converted to `\&lt;a`  How to fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus: I can't reproduce the problem which you describe. Try this with the [first](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing-Andrus.htm) or the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingFocus1.htm). Do you see and problems? Probably you have problem with the field having the custom editing?

Comment: Thank you.  Your samples does not save data. This issue occurs after the row is saved and grid is refreshed by pressing F5 key in browser. This appears in usual text column.

Comment: @Andrus: My examples do save the data, but save it locally. If you refresh the grid data pressing F5 in the browser you just reload the data from the server. I suppose that you save the data in the wrong way. Either you can make HTML decoding of the data on the client side before sending it to the server of you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` on the server side. You should just examine your code which way is better.

Comment: autoencode: true setting is used in jqgrid and HttpContext.Server.HtmlDecode() is used in server. `\&lt;a` is displayed only in non-edit mode. If inline edit starts, `\<a` appears in textbox as expceted. How to show \<a in cell if cell is not in edit mode ?

Comment: @Andrus: Could you post a test case? Can one see the problem on your demo?

Comment: @Andrus: I answered you by e-mail. All the data which jqGrid send during inline editing to the server are HTML encoded. So you can either always decode the data on the server side or decode it on the client side inside of `serializeRowData` like I describe it in the e-mail. At the first look it seems me that the encoding of the data before sending to the server is the wrong thing what jqGrid do, but I do now many things at the same time and I am not sure that this is  jqGrid bug.

Comment: Thank you. Adding serializeRowData to jqgrid property fixes this issue in inline edit but in edit and add forms problem persists. How to fix this in form edit also ? Maybe this issue is related with issue containing Tony's reply in `http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-to-edit-text-containing/` also

Comment: I added HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in server and this seems to fix this issue in both form and inline edit modes withount need to use serializeRowData